# Getting a QByteArray from a QFile and writing it in the same file

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I am going to edit the contents of a file. I  am handling the file using `QFile`. Now, I want to read it in small chunks like 1024 bytes. So far, I did :

```
QFile file("~/samplefile");

long long sizeoffile = file.size();

size = size/1024;          ///*this is for loop size devoid by 1024 because I want to run loop filesize/1024  because in each cycle I read 1024 bytes **///
QString contentsToBeErased = "sample";

QString eraser = contentsToBeErased;

eraser = eraser.fill('*');

int pos = 0;               ////** This is the position of  'contentsToBeErased' in 1024 bytes(for each cycle)  **//

QByteArray myByteArray;

if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
return;
for(long long i =0; i<size; i++)
{
  myByteArray = file.readLine(1025);   ////**1025 is used bcoz readline reads 1 less bytes**//

  int sizeArray = 0;

  QTextCodec *byteArraytoString = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");     //conevrting bytearray to string

  QString thisString = byteArraytoString->toUnicode(rohitarray);

    if(thisString.contains(contenttobeerased, Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        {
           int occurrence = thisString.count(contentsToBeErased,Qt::CaseInsensitive);
           for(int ii = 0; ii<occurrence; ii++)
            {
                pos = thisString.indexOf(contentsToBeErased, pos,Qt::CaseInsensitive);
                thisString.replace(pos,contentsToBeErased.size(), erase);
                pos = pos + contentsToBeErased.size() ;
            }

             myByteArray = thisString.toUtf8();
             sizeArray = myByteArray.length();
             QFile file1("~/samplefile");
             file1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
             file1.write(myByteArray);
             file1.close();
          }
}
```

This works fine for first attempt but in 2nd attempt, I failed to read next 1024 bytes with `readLine(1025);`. It reads the first 1024 bytes again.

So my first problem is that I don't know how to increase the `readLine();` position to get the next 1024 bytes.

And the 2nd problem is I don't know how to `write()` the 2nd byte array to file after writing first byte array, because if I only use `write()`, it will replace the previous byte array with next byte array. So how can I append the array at the end of the file?

Comment: check for `QIODevice::seek()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `seek()` for accessing specific positions in a file.

`readLine(n)` should read subsequently all bytes in chunks of size n. Your opening the same file a second time is likely to interfere here (maybe depending on your OS). You should use read, write, and seek with ONE file object which you open in `ReadWrite` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation first.
[QIODevice::readLine(qint64 maxSize = 0)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readLine-1) reads either until it encounters line feed (`"\n"`) or `maxSize` bytes.

In this specific case, you need [peek](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#peek-1) and [seek](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#seek) methods. You also need to open `QFile` with `QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::ReadWrite` [flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum)